# How to iterate two arrays for multiple conditions in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops, iteration

I have two arrays, `a = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]`, `b = ["value2", "value4"]` If elements in array "b" is already present in array "a" then I want to update it, If elements of array "b" is not present in array "a" then I want to create, If elements of array "a" is not present in array "b" then I want to delete it

I have tried `a - b, a  & b, b - a` but I couldn't loop for multiple conditions, How to iterate two arrays for create/update/delete

```
a - b => ["value1", "value3"] needs to be deleted and store it in new array "c"
a & b => ["value2"] needs to be updated and store it in new array "c"
b - a => ["value4"] needs to be created and store it in new array "c"
```

Comment: You need to clarify what you're asking. For example "If elements in array "b" is already present in array "a" then I want to update it" Update what? a or b? And are the following conditionals evaluated on the mutated data or only applicable on the initial values?

Comment: I modified the question, I need to form new array

Answer (score 0):

Try `b || a`. It will do your task.

Comment: Thanks, but it works for update/create, but I want to delete elements from array "a" which is not present in array "b"

Answer (score 0):

You could use sets for this -

```
a = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
b = ["value2", "value4"]

seta = Set.new(a)
setb = Set.new(b)

( seta - (seta - setb) ).to_a

 => ["value2"]
```